# Express Middleware Issue

Tags: node.js, express

On routes/index.js it works fine if I leave the module.exports  = routes;
But If I change it to the following to allow multiple files then I get a middleware error:

```
module.exports = {
    routes
};
```

---

```
var app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/', routes);



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Please visit: http://domain.com');
    }, (err) => {
    res.send(err);
});
```

---

//routes/index.js

```
const routes = require('./MainRoutes');
module.exports = routes;
```

---

//routes/Main Routes.js

```
const routes = require('express').Router();
routes.post('/main', (res, req) => {
   //code here works
});
module.exports = routes;
```

The error is: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainRoutes.js` exports the express router object, which middleware will understand just fine if you do

```
module.exports = routes; // routes/index.js
```

However, when you do

```
module.exports = {
    routes
};
```

You are now nesting that router object in another object, which middleware can't understand.

In your main server file you can do

```
const {routes} = require('./routes');
```

to get the router object properly.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `routes/index.js` as:

```
const routes = require('express').Router();

routes.use('/main', require('./MainRoutes'));

// Put other route paths here
// eg. routes.use('/other', require('./OtherRoutes'))

module.exports = routes;
```

Modify the `Main Routes.js` as:

```
const routes = require('express').Router();

routes.post('/', (res, req) => {
   // route controller code here
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: In index.js if I change module.exports = { routes }; then I get the same error Router.use() requires middleware function but got.... I have made all your changes and works the same just not if I want multiple exports from the index.js file...?

Comment: First... its `module.exports = routes;` and **not** `module.exports = { routes };`. In intermediate routes module, you should use `routes.use` and in the routes-controller you must use `routes.get` (or post, put etc). Also note that for making it simpler I moved the route path '/main' to intermediate routes module and in the controller I am handling '/'. You could reverse it and in this simple case of yours it will not make any difference.